# Is it possible to have a common method for background workers?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, backgroundworker

I have noticed that as the database of my application has grown, the time taken to return results has also increased. In the beginning this was negligible because it was such a small amount of time to return the data source.

Now I am at the point where it temporarily makes the UI unresponsive for a couple of seconds, but I would like to create `background workers` to do these tasks.

The problem with creating these, is that there are around 9 buttons that would need a background worker and all they do is call a different method in the DLL. Is there any way to use a common method to create these background workers using the API for background workers or should I create an `Enum` that corresponds to each button and is a parameter taken in by the method that constructs the background worker. Thus meaning I could use a simple `switch` to execute whatever method from the DLL I choose?

Sample Code:

```
    void bg_DoWorkImports(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        try
        {
            e.Result = EngineBllUtility.GetNotImportedFiles(connectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void bg_RunWorkerCompletedImports(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet temp = (DataSet)e.Result;
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            importFileGridView.DataSource = temp.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using .NET 4?  The TPL is a nice alternative to BackgroundWorker for this type of scenario...

Comment: Would taking a dependency on the Rx framework be an option, as it'd get you the TPL?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610

Comment: @ReedCopsey I'm afraid this wouldn't be my call, but I will discuss it with the senior guys in the morning. Thank you very much

Comment: Even if the TPL isn't an option (though I'd use it if it is), going to the `ThreadPool` yourself is probably a better option than `BackgroundWorker` for this scenario.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Thank you I will look into using this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass an [`Func<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) to a method that creates a BackgroundWorker and call that action from within to DoWork-event.

Something like this

```
public class BackgroundWrapper<T>
{
    private Func<T> workMethod;
    private Action<T> completeMethod;
    public static void StartBackgroundworker(Func<T> workMethod, Action<T> completeMethod)
    {
        BackgroundWrapper<T> bWrap = new BackgroundWrapper<T>();
        bWrap.workMethod = workMethod;
        bWrap.completeMethod = completeMethod;
        bWrap.Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        completeMethod((T)e.Result);
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = workMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Albin, I will explore this method.

Comment: You've essentially recreated the functionality in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. Use the right tool for the job; `BackgroundWorker` might not be the right tool here.

Comment: @AdamRobinson That was basically my idea - if your'e going to go through this, you can just use the TPL, which is nicer in a lot of ways anyways...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using BackgroundWorker, an alternative would be to use the TPL.  This would let you write the code directly within each member:

```
void buttonImport_Click(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory
      .StartNew( () => return EngineBllUtility.GetNotImportedFiles(connectionString))
      .ContinueWith( t =>
    {        
        try
        {
            if (t.Result != null)
            {
                 importFileGridView.DataSource = t.Result.Tables[0];
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I don't see why you couldn't create a "switchboard" sort of function for that. In fact, you might want to do that, because it would make things a little more modular and promote code reuse.

As far as enums go, personally, I create classes to pass lots of arguments in and out of such things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build some kind of queuing mechanism where one background worker picks up each of the button click jobs and kicks off one after other.

Comment: Kumar, this would be an undesirable feature